# Issue with the distance beween steps which are not constant when we give content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to design a vertical stepper with content in the right side. However, I am having a problem. The problem is the distance between the steps are not constant when i have the content. Because the steps distance are taken based on the height of content. How can i overcome this issue and make the distance between each step constant no matter how the long the content is ?

Here is what i have done for now

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.step {
  padding: 50px 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.v-stepper {
  position: relative;
}

.step .circle {
  background-color: #dedede;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.step .line {
  top: 24px;
  left: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid #dedede;
}

.step.completed .circle {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: rgb(6, 150, 215);
  border-color: rgb(6, 150, 215);
}

.step.completed .label {
  color: rgb(6, 150, 215);
}

.step.active .circle {
  visibility: visible;
  border-color: rgb(6, 150, 215);
}

.step.empty .circle {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.step.empty .line {
  top: 0;
  height: 150%;
}

.step:last-child .line {
  display: none;
}

.label {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.headline {
  background: #dedede;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="step completed">
    <div class="v-stepper">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="label">
      Personal
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Personal</h3>
      <p>Description on the topic personal</p>
      <h3 class="headline">Information</h3>
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="first_name" />
        <input type="text" id="last_name" />
        <input type="text" id="Phone Number" />
        <input type="text" id="email" />
        <input type="text" id="address" />
        <input type="text" id="country" />
        <input type="text" id="city" />
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <div class="v-stepper">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="label">
      Education
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <div class="v-stepper">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="label">
      Background
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

UPDATE

I mean the following way

[image]

the stepper should have constant height(the distance from one circle to another) no matter how long it's respective content has. Because I will only be showing the content of selected step.

Comment: distance between the steps you mean the distance between the circles ? so the lines should be longer or shorter ? it's kind of unclear what you are asking.

Comment: remove the padding .step {padding: 50px 10px;}

Comment: I mean to say distance between the circles.

Answer (score 0):

As the second comment by `godfather` suggested, to make circles connected to each other remove the padding top and bottom from `.step` and to keep the content of each step has its own padding just add padding to `.step .content`.

**Here's a working snippet**

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.step {
  /* Remove the padding from top and bottom*/
  /*padding: 50px 10px;*/
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
}
/* Add this to make the content of each step has its own padding */
.step .content{
  padding: 20px 0 50px;
}
.v-stepper {
  position: relative;
}

.step .circle {
  background-color: #dedede;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.step .line {
  top: 24px;
  left: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid #dedede;
}

.step.completed .circle {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: rgb(6, 150, 215);
  border-color: rgb(6, 150, 215);
}

.step.completed .label {
  color: rgb(6, 150, 215);
}

.step.active .circle {
  visibility: visible;
  border-color: rgb(6, 150, 215);
}

.step.empty .circle {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.step.empty .line {
  top: 0;
  height: 150%;
}

.step:last-child .line {
  display: none;
}

.label {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.headline {
  background: #dedede;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="step completed">
    <div class="v-stepper">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="label">
      Personal
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Personal</h3>
      <p>Description on the topic personal</p>
      <h3 class="headline">Information</h3>
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="first_name" />
        <input type="text" id="last_name" />
        <input type="text" id="Phone Number" />
        <input type="text" id="email" />
        <input type="text" id="address" />
        <input type="text" id="country" />
        <input type="text" id="city" />
      </form>
     

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <div class="v-stepper">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="label">
      Education
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Personal</h3>
      <p>Description on the topic personal</p>
      <h3 class="headline">Information</h3>
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="first_name" />
        <input type="text" id="last_name" />
        <input type="text" id="Phone Number" />
        <input type="text" id="email" />
        <input type="text" id="address" />
        <input type="text" id="country" />
        <input type="text" id="city" />
      </form>
     

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <div class="v-stepper">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="label">
      Background
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: sorry my explanation was not clear. I wanted the stepper be constant. I mean, the stepper's height should not depend on its respective content. I hope you understand me.